# gem install rails fails at binding_of_caller gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm trying to get rails working and can't get past a `binding_of_caller` gem that tries to install with the other gems after running `sudo gem install rails`. I don't think the gem is required for rails to work, but can't figure out how to skip it, or stop it from trying to install.

Every time the list of gems gets to `binding_of_callers` I get the following:

```
Installing binding_of_callers (0.6.9) with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
xcrun cc -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common  -O0 -std=c99  -c binding_of_caller.c
binding_of_caller.c:4:10: fatal error: 'vm_core.h' file not found
#include "vm_core.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [binding_of_caller.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ericavirtue/.bundler/tmp/54559/gems/binding_of_caller-0.6.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ericavirtue/.bundler/tmp/54559/gems/binding_of_caller-0.6.9/ext/binding_of_caller/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing binding_of_caller (0.6.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install binding_of_caller -v '0.6.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm running `OSX 10.8.2` and using pow web server with rbenv to manage ruby. I'm also running ruby `1.9.3-p385`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try updating the gem:

`$ bundle update binding_of_caller`

Comment: Note that this _is_ the answer if you got this error when upgrading to Ruby 2.0. That's because you probably need to update binding_of_caller to 0.7.1. Found here: http://www.gavinmorrice.com/blog/posts/37-ruby-2-0-0-an-error-occurred-while-installing-binding_of_caller

Comment: You probably need to run `bundle update` as a whole .. but yes this is the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Before installing Rails, add the gem with the following (also note that the gem name is singular):

```
$ gem install binding_of_caller
```

Then run:

```
$ bundle update rails
```

Or:

```
$ gem install rails
```

(Or whatever rbenv offers)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't even get that far. I get an error whenever I try to get install the gem. I'll get some offline help and post the solution when I have it.

Comment: Are you getting the same error message as in the original post?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem was that the RBENV ruby version wasn't being recognized as the version of ruby being used by the project. So after trying to get rbenv working for a while, I switched back to RVM went through some debugging, and installed some dependencies, I got ruby 2.0.0p0 installed, and recognized as the project ruby. Then I was able to bundle. So to answer my question ... It was a ruby version issue.

Answer (score 1):

Has there been any progress in solving this problem using rbenv?

I'm using rbenv to load jruby 2.0 locally and I would like to continue using this solution rather than rvm.

```
Ascended:Ascended foundation3 $ rbenv local
jruby-1.7.4
Ascended:Ascended foundation3 $ jruby --version
jruby 1.7.4 (2.0.0) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509 [darwin-x86_64]
Ascended:Ascended foundation3 $ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

My ~/.jrubyconf is set to

```
compat.version=2.0                                                                                                         
cext.enabled=true                                                               
errno.backtrace=true
```

when I try to install binding of caller I get the following -

```
Ascended:Ascended foundation3 $ gem install binding_of_caller -v '0.7.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing binding_of_caller:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby extconf.rb
/Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:1:in `(root)': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and depreca
ted Config.
/Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:1791:in `init_mkmf': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
/Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:1791:in `init_mkmf': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and $eprecated Config.
creating Makefile

make
cc -I. -I/Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/native/include -I/Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/nati$e/include/ruby -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE      -fPIC -DTARGET_RT_MAC_CFM=0  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-al$asing  -fexceptions   -O0 -std=c99  -arch x86_64 -c binding_of_caller.c
binding_of_caller.c:4:10: fatal error: 'vm_core.h' file not found
#include "vm_core.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [binding_of_caller.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7$2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Ascended/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/ext/binding_of$caller/gem_make.out
```

Now according to the answer that is marked correct in this thread, this is an issue with rbenv, but jruby 1.7.4 is the right version that is sourced and it is operating at 2.0. Shouldn't this work? What am I not understanding?

Comment: The problem I was having with rbenv was that it wasn't loading the proper version of ruby for my environment. I would do the command to change my ruby version, and it just wouldn't take. That ruby issue ended up being the reason `binding_of_caller` wouldn't build, and is why I switched back to rvm. If `ruby -v` is returning the expected version of ruby, I'm not sure what you need to do.

Comment: Okay, I couldn't get it to work last night so I've just stopped using pry-debugger for the time being, but not being able to install a gem like that severely reduces ruby's ability to introspect, I will need to figure a work around soon.

Comment: Please post if you do, and I'll give you the check mark, because I'd rather return to using rbenv.

Answer (score -3):

Looks like youre using Linux.  Try following the rails installation by installing ruby and rvm first.  It might be cause of an outdated ruby version.  throw in the dark though.

Comment: I'm running OSX 10.8.2 and using pow web server with rbenv to manage ruby. I'm also running ruby 1.8.7 p-358. I'm totally lost here. I've spent all afternoon/night trying to get this working. I'll update the question with the above info and try to update my ruby.

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.9.3-p385 now. Same problem. The issue as far as I can tell is binding_of_caller, so I believe the solution involves skipping, or removing that gem, or somehow resolving the issue above.

Comment: says that vm_core.h is not found.  try this gem install ruby-debug19 -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p385

Comment: I'm not using RVM. I'm using rbenv to manage my rubies. rbenv isn't compatible with RVM. The error is with the Makefile, I believe. That is where the error is originating.

Comment: vm_core.h is part of Ruby core. It looks like you didn't build your environment on your own machine, but got a binary from somewhere. If you would build you environment on your own machine you would have the vm_core.h header file. I'm on 10.8 and I used http://railsinstaller.org/ to install the Ruby and Rails stack on my machine, which worked realy well.

Comment: I don't think so. I think the issue is with the Makefile not being found, so it cant build properly.

Comment: I'm having this same issue - any luck yet?

Comment: Yeah, it was a ruby issue. Make sure the version of ruby your project needs is actually being used by the project. My solution was to make ruby 2.0.0p0 my default global ruby. So typing ruby -v gives me 2.0.0p0. The problem I had before was that rbenv was saying my ruby version was the right version, but my system ruby was still showing as 1.8.7, and that is what the problems above were caused by.